# Add decimal to string if a decimal does not appear between string end and specified characters

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm writing a basic calculator program and am implementing decimals. In trying to devise a way to append a decimal to an operand, I come into the problem of decimal duplication.

```
"5.5.5" // shouldn't be possible, ignore second . addition
"5.5 + 5.5" or "5 + 5.5" // wonderful!
```

I have some code like this:

```
String expression = "";
...
//various methods to append numbers, operators, etc to string
...
addDecimal() {
    if (expression.equals("")) {
        expression += "0."; // if no operand, assume it's 0-point-something
    } else {
        if(/* some condition */) {
            expression += ".";
            //note it is appending a decimal to the end of the expression
            //ie at the end of the rightmost operand
        }
    }
}
```

Operators are `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`. A more declarative description of what I'm trying to do is:

```
check string if it contains a decimal
    if not, addDecimal()
    if so, split string by operators above, look at the rightmost operand; does it contain a decimal?
        if not, addDecimal()
        if so, do nothing
```

eg.

```
expression = "2";
addDecimal(); //expression is now "2."
//append decimal to only operand

expression = "5.5 + 4";
addDecimal(); //expression is now "5.5 + 4."
//append a decimal to rightmost operand

expression = "7.5";
addDecimal(); //expression is now "7.5"
//if an operand contains a decimal already, it cannot have another

expression = "2 + 5";
addDecimal(); //expression is now "2 + 5."
//note the decimal was only appended to the rightmost operand
//ignoring the leftmost operand
```

The congruent rule is that a decimal is only appended to the rightmost operand, not to all operands within the expression.

Comment: Your approach looks arguable. I would revise the entities you're using in your architecture. For example I do not tend to consider "5.5 + 4." an expression. I would first build a number with no respect to "expression" and then insert it to the "expression"

Comment: @AlexeyR.as it's a calculator, it's done in steps (keypresses). It can be assumed a person will input another number after a decimal, or I would consider a "4." to mean "4.0" as I've done with "." becoming "0.".

Comment: I see. Sorry it was not quite clear what was the input supposed. Then it migh make sense to implement a kind of state machine that is fed with a symbol and takes decision depending on the state it is in currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this lookaround based regex for replacement:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<!\\.)\\b\\d+\\b(?!\\.)(?!.*\\d)", "$0.");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9LcYcL/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?<!\\.)`: Assert we don't have dot at previous position
- `\\b\\d+\\b`: Match one or more digits with word boundaries
- `(?!\\.)`: Assert we don't have dot ahead
- `(?!.*\d)`: Make sure we are the right most operand

Comment: What about "2+5"? This yields "2.+5." when expected would be "2+5.".

Comment: If `5.5 + 4` is expected to become `5.5 + 4.` (both decimals) then why `2+5` should not become `2.+5.` ?

Comment: Perhaps a decimal is only desired to be appended to the 5, not the 2? Not every operand needs a decimal.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `String.split`.

**e.g.**

```
String[] splitExpression = expression.split(".");
if(splitExpression.length > 2){
    expression = splitExpression[0] + "." + splitExpression[1];
}
else {
    // Either a valid decimal or no decimal number at all
}
```